# Using Mock in Python for nested objects (DynamoDB and Table)

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I want to test the behavior on a function with different inputs from a DynamoDb. There are two main behaviors: when the search key is found in the table and when it is not. Here is a minimal code of the function:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def main(symbol):
   dynamo = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
   table = dynamo.Table("mytable")
   data = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("symbol").eq(symbol))

   if data.count > 0:
      # result = some_output
   else:
      result = {'status': '404'}
   return result
```

and I want to test this code with a unit test by sending empty results and a list of non-empty items, something along these lines:

```
import boto3
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class TestMainHandler(unittest.TestCase): 
   ...
   def test_main_fails_on_wrong_symbol(self):
       with patch.object(main_handler, 'table') as get_mock:
          get_mock.return_value = []
          result = main('dummy_symbol')
          expect_result = {'status': '404'}
   self.assertEqual(result, expect_result)
```

but I can't run the mock part. I was wondering if you could guide me how to mock the nested table and dynamo variables. I highly appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend mocking the first "integration point" you can, then building your mock results off of that. In this case, it would be `boto3.resource`. From there, you can modify the return value of `boto3.resource` to be a mock table. Then you can change the return value of any call on your mock table to be your expected result.

```
import boto3
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class TestMainHandler(unittest.TestCase): 
    @patch('boto3.resource')
    def test_main_fails_on_wrong_symbol(self, mock_dynamo):
        mock_table = Mock()
        mock_table.query.return_value = []
        mock_dynamo.Table.return_value = mock_table

        result = main('dummy_symbol')
        expected_result = {'status': '404'}
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)
```

Also note that I used the patch decorator on the test case rather than the context manager. This is a matter of preference for me, but I think it looks cleaner.

EDIT: I had an error when assigning the return value for the `mock_dynamo` function call. I also filled in your `if` to test the length of the queried data and return something. That branch is not reached by the test here though. Here's the final product:

```
"""boto_main.py"""
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def main(symbol):
   dynamo = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
   table = dynamo.Table("mytable")
   data = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("symbol").eq(symbol))
   if len(data) > 0:
      result = {'status': '200'}
   else:
      result = {'status': '404'}
   return result
```

---

```
"""boto_test.py"""
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from boto_main import main

class TestMainHandler(unittest.TestCase): 
    @patch('boto3.resource')
    def test_main_fails_on_wrong_symbol(self, mock_dynamo):
        mock_table = Mock()
        mock_table.query.return_value = []
        mock_dynamo.return_value.Table.return_value = mock_table
        result = main('dummy_symbol')
        expected_result = {'status': '404'}
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)
```

Comment: Very nice idea @wholevinski. I'll implement it per you suggestion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wrote the code exactly as you suggested but it seems the path is not being applied. Here is the error that I receive:
`botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the Query operation: Requested resource not found`. Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to test it out right now, but to debug it you may want to place a `pdb.set_trace()` in the function you're testing and see what's not being mocked. I tested it as written and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome. It'll be a few days before I can try it out again, but I'll see if I can debug further.

Comment: You are amazing man. So the magic was the second .return_value, right? It works like a charm now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, so this line: `@patch('boto3.resource')` mocks the function. So I was essentially assigning `Table.return_value ... ` to an attribute on the `Mock` instance (which was wrong). The missing `.return_value` made it so whenever that mock function is called, the expected return value is returned.

Comment: I still don't get it. What is mock_dynamo here? It looks like an undefined variable to me. maybe I should define it somewhere before?

Comment: @Afshinzkh mock_dynamo is passed in by the decorator for that test case. If you have more questions, please open a new question so we don't flood the comments here and can work on your specific use-case as well.