# How to mock multiple dynamodb tables using moto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, moto

I have a function create which uses 3 dynamodb tables. How do i mock three Dynamo db tables?

```
def create():
    //This function uses a dynamodb table "x"
    // Then it calls my_table() function

def my_table():
    // This function basically uses two dynamodb table "y" and "z"
    // This function returns a value which is used in create() function.
```

My test file has following code -

```
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"DYNAMODB_TABLE": "x",
'second_TABLE': "y",
'Third_TABLE': "z"
})
def test_create():

    dynamodb_test()
    event = {  // my event values}

    result = create(event)
    assert result == 200




def dynamodb_test():

    with mock_dynamodb2():
        dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
        dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName=os.environ["DYNAMODB_TABLE"],
            KeySchema=[
                {
                'AttributeName': 'id',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'
                }
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                'AttributeName': 'id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
                }
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 1
            }
        )
        yield dynamodb
```

whenever i am testing test_create() function using pytest , i am getting

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when
> calling the Scan operation: The security token included in the request is expired

I think its trying to access the actual aws dynamo db but i want it to use mock dynamodb. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moto only works when two conditions are met:

- The logic to be tested is executed inside a Moto-context
- The Moto-context is started before any boto3-clients (or resources) are created

The Moto-context in your example, `with mock_dynamodb2()`, is localized to the `dynamodb_test`-function. After the function finishes, the mock is no longer active, and Boto3 will indeed try to access AWS itself.

###### Solution

The following test-function would satisfy both criteria:

```
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"DYNAMODB_TABLE": "x",
'second_TABLE': "y",
'Third_TABLE': "z"
})
# Initialize the mock here, so that it is effective for the entire test duration
@mock_dynamodb2
def test_create():

    dynamodb_test()
    event = {  // my event values}

    # Ensure that any boto3-clients/resources created in the logic are initialized while the mock is active
    from ... import create

    result = create(event)
    assert result == 200

def dynamodb_test():

    # There is no need to start the mock-context again here, so create the table immediately
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
    dynamodb.create_table(...)
```

---

The test code you provided does not talk about creating tables `y` and `z` - if the logic expects them to exist, you'd have to create them manually as well of course (just like table `x` was created in `dynamodb_test`.

---

Documentation for the import quirk can be found here: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html#recommended-usage

Comment: Thanks Bert,  this is what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830635/using-mock-in-python-for-nested-objects-dynamodb-and-table) is almost identical to yours. You could try this or utilize some of the other existing tools like `localstack` or `dynamodb-local`. The Python client for localstack for example: https://github.com/localstack/localstack-python-client

EDIT:
I see your title explains you want to use moto. I don't see you importing moto any of the moto modules into your code. See the last snippet in [this page](https://github.com/spulec/moto) and replace `s3` with either `dynamodb`, `dynamodb2` (whichever you are using)

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately i cant use that answer as i have to do it using moto only. I have not added modules cause i just want to get rough idea of how to achieve it so have put only the code.